# Cell tower location

Tags: android, geolocation

I am new to android. I was wondering if there was way to locate Cell towers (ie. get gps coordinates)  ? I have written the code which gives me LAC, CID and RSSI of neighboring Cell towers.

Comment: Do you actually want the location of the *cell tower* itself, or do you just want the location of the phone?

Comment: I actually want the location of the cell tower itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be possible, simply log the current location with the RSSI of the basestation and when enough data is gathered try and calculate the position of the Cell tower. I would also suggest taking a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94679) which asks the same question from a non-programming perspective.

A cheap way of doing the estimation would be taking last 3 measuring points (you probably want to make sure that they are x meters away from each other for better accuracy) and then using triangulation to estimate the position of the cell power. When enough measurements have been done, but calculating the average you would probably get a fair estimate of the location of the base station.